# jQuery UI DatePicker question

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have 2 input fields and i am using it with a DatePicker like this

```
$("#depart, #return").datepicker({
     showOn: 'both',
     buttonImage: 'images/icon_calendar.gif',
     buttonImageOnly: true,
     numberOfMonths:2,
     dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
});
```

At some point i want to remove the return field and i am doing it with the .remove() method. Then using the .after method i'm adding again this field to the form. But the datepicker functionality is not available.

It makes sense, but i don't know how to re-assign a date picker to the newly created field?

Comment: why don't you just hide the "return" thing for a while?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the field again, you need to call .datepicker on the field

**[Working Demo to demonstrate](http://jsbin.com/upihu)**

*Note about demo: since the add buttons will add a text input with id="return", adding more than one will mess up the input to which the datepicker is attached.*

```
$("[where you're inserting]").after("<input id='return' type='text' />");

$('#return').datepicker({
     showOn: 'both',
     buttonImage: 'images/icon_calendar.gif',
     buttonImageOnly: true,
     numberOfMonths:2,
     dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });
```

I would recommend just [hiding](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/hide) the input then [showing](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/show) it again when you need to, rather than removing then re-inserting into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to reassign in right after you re-add it.

Something like this:

```
$("#return").remove();

$("something").after(myReturnfield);

$("#return").datepicker(myDatepickerSettings);
```

Comment: that's what i thought but i am not sure if when i remove it the initial datepicker object is destroyed or is still active.

Comment: No, I think the way datepicker works is just adds event listener to selected objects. Once the object is destroyed, listener won't work for this particular one, but it won't affect the other.